# Error in running Spark on Mesos in docker

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I have two nodes with docker. Zookeeper,Mesos and Spark were installed on each docker. I specify "slaves" on "slaves" file that I have just one master and one slave. Also, I have a "docker-compose.yaml" on each node in the same path. I do "docker-compose up" in each node. Then in the master node,inside docker,I run dispatcher:

```
  "/home/spark/sbin/start-mesos-dispatcher.sh     --master 
  mesos://150.20.11.136:5050".
```

After that I run my program with this command:

```
 "/home/spark/bin/spark-submit --name test_mesos --master 
 mesos://150.20.11.136:5050 --executor-cores 4 --executor-memory 6G -- 
 files iran2.npy --py-files a.zip myprogram.py".
```

When running my program, I get this error:

> Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I have searched a lot. I disable firewall, first time it worked;but now I does not work at all. Moreover, I openned all port in docker via "expose" in docker compose file. I decreased resources in Submit command. But none of them solved my problem.

Would you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran docker with this command and my program was run without any errors. But it took a lot of time, I do not know maybe it is because of Mesos.

```
Sudo docker run --network host -it ubuntu_mesos_spark_python3.6_oraclient
```

I hope this point solved others problem.